# Replacing adsl with hotspot

Tags: modem, hotspot

I have just bought a 4G/3G wifi hotspot (D-Link DWR-932) and I would like to use it as a backup to my home ADSL connection.

I have a rather elaborate home LAN. My router is a TP-Link TL-R480T+ which supports multiple WAN connections, and up to now I have used two phone lines each with its own D-Link DSL-320B ADSL modem. The router connects by Cat5 to several wifi routers, giving me both Cat5 and WiFi at various locations. This has all been working well for a number of years.

Phone line faults are quite common where I live, and having two lines gives me some extra security. But now I think the hotspot should do that job better, and I can save money by ending one of my fixed line accounts.

My question is, **how can I connect the router to the hotspot?** The router has only Cat5 sockets for WAN connection, and the hotspot has no sockets except micro-USB. The micro-USB is used for charging, and also for initial configuration of the hotspot. If I could use some sort of dongle to connect it by Cat5 to the router, that would be ideal. Otherwise, I suppose I need to use a wireless device that has a Cat5 socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another access point to make a bridge between your 4G router and your main router that supports Multi-Wan. Configure it to connect to the 4G hotspot and use a cable between the access point and the main router.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried setting up a TL-WR840N as a bridge. I enable WDS and it does connect to the hotspot. In fact I can tell the main router to use Dynamic IP (instead of PPPoE) for WAN2 and it gets an IP from the hotspot. But from the LAN I can't connect to internet, or even to manage the hotspot. I must be missing something.